# How to sum up selective dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x

I want to filter specific departments salary and sum up, I have done first half, but adding those salary, can any one suggest by seeing the below code....

```
chennai   = {"name": "Kumar", "Department": "Sales",     "Age": 39,"Salary": 20}
mumbai  = {"name": "Suresh","Department": "Finance",   "Age": 53,"Salary": 35}
delhi  = {"name": "Babu",  "Department": "QC",        "Age": 28,"Salary": 10}
kolkata = {"name": "Satish","Department": "Production","Age": 34,"Salary": 15}
madurai = {"name": "Dev",   "Department": "Management","Age": 45,"Salary": 23}
hyderabad = {"name": "Rani",  "Department": "Marketing", "Age": 46,"Salary": 25}
bengalore  = {"name": "Devi",  "Department": "Production","Age": 24,"Salary": 5}
cochin  = {"name": "Sarath","Department": "Production","Age": 26,"Salary": 12}
jaipur  = {"name": "Senu",  "Department": "Production","Age": 25,"Salary": 8}
shimla  = {"name": "Kumari","Department": "Management","Age": 37,"Salary": 20}
lucknow  = {"name": "Sanjay","Department": "Marketing", "Age": 52,"Salary": 30}

employ = [chennai,mumbai,delhi,kolkata,madurai,hyderabad,bengalore,cochin,jaipur,shimla,lucknow]

#Finding Production unit salary expenditure
for x in employ:
    sums = 0
    if x ["Department"] == 'Production':
        print x["Salary"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a one-liner

```
result = sum(d.get("Salary", 0) for d in employ if d.get("Department") == "Production")
```

Can also total sum for multiple.

```
departments = {"Production", "Marketing"}
result = sum(d.get("Salary", 0) for d in employ if d.get("Department") in departments)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd
# Creating the dataframe
dataset = pd.DataFrame(employ)
print (dataset)
#Out[3]: 
#    Age  Department  Salary    name
#0    39       Sales      20   Kumar
#1    53     Finance      35  Suresh
#2    28          QC      10    Babu
#3    34  Production      15  Satish
#4    45  Management      23     Dev
#5    46   Marketing      25    Rani
#6    24  Production       5    Devi
#7    26  Production      12  Sarath
#8    25  Production       8    Senu
#9    37  Management      20  Kumari
#10   52   Marketing      30  Sanjay

# Production Salary
dataset1 = dataset[dataset['Department'] == 'Production'].Salary
print (dataset1)
#Out[6]: 
#3    15
#6     5
#7    12
#8     8
#Name: Salary, dtype: int64

# Sum Salaries
dataset2 = dataset[dataset['Department'] == 'Production'].Salary.sum()
print (dataset2)
# 40
```

The code above does not look so pretty, but pandas is very powerful.
Here is how you can get the total salary by department:

```
dataset3 = dataset.groupby('Department').sum()['Salary']
print (dataset3)
#Out[8]:
#Department
#Finance       35
#Management    43
#Marketing     55
#Production    40
#QC            10
#Sales         20
#Name: Salary, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use pandas try this,

```
from collections import defaultdict
salary = defaultdict(int)
# for specific departments
required_departments = ["Production"]
for i in employ:
    if i["Department"] in required_departments:
        salary[i["Department"]] += i["Salary"]
print(salary)
# for all departments
salary = defaultdict(int)
for i in employ:
    salary[i["Department"]] += i["Salary"]

print(salary)
```